# Is it possible to use spread out operator to set the react component props?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I wanted to use spread operator to set the component props. This is mainly because I don't want to use state for each of the props value. Is this possible? The code below returns an error saying that the props are missing. Thanks in advance!

```
const compProps = { 
    label: 'Test Label',
    value: 'Test Value',
    icon: 'test-icon'
}

<CustomComp {...compProps} />
```

**Update:**

I'm using TS on react, as strongly typed language, it doesn't allow me to have an undefined props as initial value. I managed to fix this by checking the props first.

```
{ compProps && 
    <CustomComp {...compProps} /> }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can do that, But you need to use spread operator inside braces.

`const compProps = { 
   label: 'Test Label',
   value: 'Test Value',
   icon: 'test-icon'
 }

 <CustomComp {...compProps} />`

In Child component you can access props like this `props.label`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use as below.

```
const compProps = { 
  label: 'Test Label',
  value: 'Test Value',
  icon: 'test-icon'
}

<CustomComp {...compProps} />
```

Comment: Actually this is what I did. It turns out TS is strict on initial value, so what need to do is check the props first, make sure that it's not undefined before showing the component.

Comment: Check this sand box link https://codesandbox.io/s/red-cache-8m7hg?file=/src/App.tsx.      We can mention types for props we receive in component and using defaultProps in react we can mention initial value to props.